# Confirm Web Access

Tags: php, javascript, html, splash-screen

I want to display a confirmation page to enter my website the time when the user enters it.

I don't know if it's possible with PHP or Javascript.

Comment: couple of options here ... you could do a referrer check and if the url is not your sites display, or you could check for the absence of a cookie then set it.

Comment: yes its very much possible ,you can try

Comment: Let me see if I understand, you want the user to go to your page, and then say "yes, I really want to go to your page"?

Comment: That seems like basic html/php? Or maybe I'm not understanding the question.

Comment: the only sites that should do this are porn sites asking me if over 18

Comment: No, it's beacause i don't know which one is better

Comment: And... No it's not a porn site ahahahaha.

Comment: His point was that it's annoying for a site to do this, and the only reason they should have to is if it's a legal requirement. (I think that was his point at least.)

Comment: then don't do it, its just annoying to users, and will block some -what about search engines? @JohnVanDeWeghe no i just need some more porn to look at ;-)

Comment: Ahahahaha maybe if in the future i make a porn site, i will write you @Dragon xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons, it is best to use cookie sent with `php`. They can have `HTTPOnly` flag in them and client cannot modify it. Some browsers support this. You can do the diggings if it interests you.

Comment: Mmm... well, you answered my question, that's my dude, which one is better. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can set a cookie if the user press yes (confirm to enter your site) check whether cookie is set if not redirect to confirmation page

Comment: but which one do you prefer, js or php?

Comment: you are using COOKIES => `php`

Comment: yeah but long time ago i saw it with javascript

Comment: that's up to you,both php and js you can set cookie and there is some difference